# How to load custom .env file in Laravel console command?

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, phpdotenv

I have this console command code:

```php
class MyCommand extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'custom:mycommand {domain}';

    // ...

    public function handle()
    {
        $domain = $this->argument('domain');

        // read domain based .env file, like: .env.example.com
        $dotenv = \Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(base_path(), '.env.' . $domain);
        $dotenv->load();

        dd(env('APP_URL'));

        // ...

        return 0;
    }
}
```

In the line of `dd()` it should print the domain what I gave as parameter (coming from `.env.example.com`, but still print the data from `.env` file.

Otherwise this function is working well in `AppServiceProvider` with this code:

```php
$host = request()->getHost();

// read domain based .env file, like: .env.example.com
$dotenv = \Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(base_path(), '.env.' . $host);
$dotenv->load();
```

Any idea how can I make it work in console command?

Comment: Have you tried `$app->loadEnvironmentFrom('.env.example.com');` where `$app` is you Laravel Application.

Comment: yes, also didn't worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Immutability** refers to if Dotenv is allowed to overwrite existing environment variables.

If you want Dotenv to overwrite existing environment variables, use as **Mutable** instead.

This is how I used it.

```
   $env_name = $this->argument('env_name');
   if(!empty($env_name) && is_string($env_name)){
        $dotenv = \Dotenv\Dotenv::createMutable(base_path(), $env_name);
        try{
             $dotenv->load();
             $this->info(env('NAME'));
             $this->info('The Dotenv was loaded successfully!');
        } catch(\Dotenv\Exception\InvalidPathException $e){
             $this->error($e->getTraceAsString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: `\Dotenv\Dotenv::createMutable` was the solution! Thanks!